# SUM of time spent in a State

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please consider the table below for call center agent states.
What I need is to calculate the **sum** of time **Bryan** spent in "**Break**" for the whole day.

[image: Break_Sum]

This is what I'm trying to execute but it returns some inaccurate values:

```
    select sum (CASE   
    WHEN State = 'Not Working' and Reason = 'Break'
    THEN Datediff(SECOND, [Time_Stamp], CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    else '' END) as Break_Overall
    from MyTable
    where Agent = 'Bryan'
```

Comment: using [Time_Stamp] suggest you are using SQL-server instead of MySQL.. please check if you have tagged the correct database.

Comment: Tag updated, thanks @Raymond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `lead()`:

```
select agent,
       sum(datediff(second, timestamp, next_timestamp) 
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by agent order by time_stamp) as next_timestamp
      from mytable t
     ) t
where state = 'Not Working' and reason = 'Break'
group by agent;
```

If the agent can currently be on break, you might want a default value:

```
select agent,
       sum(datediff(second, timestamp, next_timestamp) 
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp, 1, current_timestamp) over (partition by agent 
                                                         order by time_stamp) as next_timestamp
      from mytable t
     ) t
where state = 'Not Working' and reason = 'Break'
group by agent;
```

I'm a little uncomfortable with this logic, because `current_timestamp` has a date component, but your times don't.

EDIT:

In SQL Server 2008, you can do:

```
select agent,
       sum(datediff(second, timestamp, coalesce(next_timestamp, current_timestamp)) 
from (select t.*, t2.timestamp as next_timestamp
      from mytable t outer apply
           (select top 1 t2.*
            from mytable t2
            where t2.agent = t.agent and t2.time_stamp > t.time_stamp
            order by t.time_stamp
           ) t2
     ) t
where state = 'Not Working' and reason = 'Break'
group by agent;
```

Comment: Thank you @Gordon, I'm using SQL 2008, LEAD doesn't work.
Any alternatives please?

Answer (score 0):

As it is, you're getting the difference between the record's Time_Stamp and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  That's probably not correct - you probably want to get the difference between the record's Time_Stamp and the *next* Time_Stamp for the same "Agent".

(Note that "Agent" will also present problems if you have multiple Agents with the same name; you probably want to store Agents in a different table and use a unique identifier as a foreign key.)

So, for Bryan, you'd get
`the sum of both the "total time" for the 8:30:21 record AND the 11:34:58 record`, which is right - except that you're calculating "total time" incorrectly, so instead you'd get `the sum of the time since 8:30:21 and 11:34:58`.